# simultanious read/write on the same serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am building an application that intersepts a serial comunication line by recieving the transmition, modifieng the data, and echoing the changed result.

The transmitted data is made of status sentances at high baudrate with alot of data.

I have created two threads, one reads the sentaces and pushes a pointer to each new sentance into a queue, and the Other pops the pointers out of the queue, manipulates them, sends them to the serial port and deletes the pointer.

The queue operstions are in external functions with CririticalSection locks so that works fine.

To make sure the queue doesnt overflow quickly i need to send the messages quickly and not wait for the recieving to end.

To my understanding serial ports can recieve and transmit simultaniously  but trying to do so gives error with access resttictions.

The other solution is to split the system into two diffrent ports but I try to avoid it because the hardware changes and the need of another USB and convertor.

I read about Overlapped structures but didnt fully understood what is their usage and, as I got it they manage asinc operation where my issue is parallel operation.

Sorry for my lame english, any help or explanation will help.

I used this class for the serial comunication, setting overlapped to enable when opening the comport to allow wait event timeouts:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C

Thanks in advance.

Roman.

Clarification: 
Im not opening the port twice, just once in the main program and pass the handler to both threads (writing it now maximizes the problem  in this approach

More details:

The error comes from the Cserial library:
 "Cserial::read overlapped complete without result." Commenting the send back to serial command in the sending thread will not raise an error and the queue is filled and displays correctly–

Im on a classified system without internet access so i cant upload the sample, writing from my tablet. The error accures after I get the first sentace, which triggers the first send command ss soon as queues size changes, and then the recieving thread exits because recieve failes, so the queue stops to fill and nothing sends out.

Probbly because both use same serial handler but whats the alternative to access the same port simultaniosly without locking one thread or the other

Ignoring error 996, which is the error id of the "read overlapped completed without results" and not exiting the thread when its detected makes both recieve an transmited data wrong (missing bytes)

At the buttom line, after asking alot of questions:

Why a read operation is interrupted by a write operation if these are two seperate comunication lines?can i use two handlers one for each task on the same port?

Is the D+/- in usb is transmit/recieve or both line used for transmit and recieve?

Comment: The only thing you could be doing wrong is trying to open the port more than once.  Not supported, the threads need to use the same HANDLE.

Comment: Interesting question. Are you accessing the serial via a USB to serial convertor or a serial port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

":read overlapped complete without result"

Are you preventing the read from being interrupted by the OS switching execution to the write thread?  You need to protect this from happening by using a mutex or similar.

The real solution is to switch to an asynchronous library, such as bosst::asio.

*Why a read operation is interrupted by a write operation if these are two seperate comunication lines?*

here is a possible hand-waving visualization of what happens if you use synchronous operations in two threads without locking them against each other. ( I am guessing at the details of how you arranged your software )

- Your app receives a read request from the port.
- Your app requests the OS to start the read thread.
- OS agrees, and your read thread completes the read.
  -. Your app does its processing.
- Your app asks the OS to start the write thread.
- The OS agrees, and your write thread starts a write.
- A second read request arrives on the port.  This does not interrupt anything, it just waits.
- The write is not yet finished, but the OS decides that the write thread has had enough time.  It decides to switch context to the read thread which is waiting.
- The read thread starts reading
- Again the OS decides that the running thread ( read ) has had a fair crack at the CPU .  It switches context back to the write thread. This crashes the unfinished read.  Note that this happens in your software, not in the hardware, or the hardware driver.

This should give you a general insight into the sort of problems that occur, unless you keep the OS from running the reads and writes over the top of each other.  It is a matter of opinion wehter it is better to use multithreading with mutexes ( or equivalent ) or asynchronous event-driven designs.

Comment: The error comes from  the Cserial library: Cserial::read overlapped complete without result.  Commenting the writing back to serial in the sending thread doesnt raise an error so its dye to the operation of both read and right

Comment: Im on a classified system without internet access so i cant upload the sample, writing from my tablet. The error accures after I get the first sentace, which triggers the first send command, and then the recieving thread exits because recieve failes, so the queue stops to fill and nothing sends out.

Comment: The point is to be in a constant state of intertuption, i need both read and write to work simultaniously, as if they are two indepandent ports. the hardware (convertor) allows it. Im afraid that because of the usage of mutex the read will not allow the write, and once it does the write will interrupt the read and bytes will be missed. The reciever is a smart black box that needs a constant flawless feedback

Comment: Not sure what to say in response to your comment, except to repeat that you need to move to using an asynchronous library, such as boost::asio.  The whole point of synchronous reads and writes is that they cannot interrupt each other.  The problem is in the software, not the hardware

Comment: Hard to bring it in here without internet access :(  ill try to achive this at home and then get it back here.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: What I dont get is why read and wright interrupt each other in the first place, serial communication is bidirectional :/, so two diffrent data lines are used for the operations

Comment: "What I dont get is ..."  You are focussing on the hardware.  The problem is in the software.  The OS decides to switch to the other thread in the middle of a send.  This is why threading is "bad" ( you need to muck about with mutexes to prevent the OS from screwing up your operations ) and event driven asynchronous design is "better" ( no mutexes required )  IMHO

Comment: Ok, Im almost sattled, last question please: if the pc has several cores, and I lock the read/wright lines in the threads using diffrent mutexes with high priority, they both will not be interrupted and theoretcly bidirectional i/o shuld work?    Just for understanding the flow, i am going to implement your advice Thanks

Comment: As for the architecture of the app: both read and wright threads run in a while loop where the exit condition for the reading thread is a serial port error or a raised flag (the main app waits for the thread to exit after setting the flag). The send thread is polling the queue for elements and trys to emty it by sending yhe sentances to serial. Both threads are independant and run in the background, they dont lock each other.  The read thread us always reading, with a timeout set for a single read, if the operation exits with time out event i have to stop everything, in no scenario the r

Comment: As I have tried to explain, if you run your code in separate threads then you need to lock them against each other while the synchronous operations do their things.

Comment: Yeah but " locking against each other" sounds like the opposite of what im trying to achive, I dont want that one will wait for the other to finish, they both shuldnt be interrupted, not by eachother and not by anything else, asynchronous or locking means that? I guess i sound alittle dumb.. :/

Comment: If you want the reads and writes to run simultaneously, you need to do them asynchronously.  For this you need to use a library such as boost::asio  Maybe I already said this?

Comment: Yep, only 3 times :). I got it clearly now, thank you for your patience!! The root of the problem was in my understanding of the word asynchronously.

Comment: "Asynchronous" == "non-blocking"

Answer (score 0):

Two threads can't operate on single port / file descriptior. Depending on what library you used you should try to do this asynchronous or by checking how many bytes can be read/write without blocking thread. (if it is Linux raw filedescriptor you should look at poll / select)

Comment: And if i create two serial ports that dont block each other and use one to send and the other to recieve?

Comment: if there are two different physical interfaces it is ok, but you can't access twice to the same physical port.

Comment: At the buttom line, can data come in and out of the same port in the same time using c++?  I cannot allow recieving to be intercepted by sending. And all the recieved data has to be echoed. Again, adding another pott is a simple solution which i try to avoid at the moment simply because i dont have another convertor and will be unable to debug the recieving side.

Comment: "i dont have another convertor and will be unable to debug the recieving side"  You can use a null modem simulator - very useful for this kind of work.  http://www.aggsoft.com/virtual-null-modem/download.htm